# Import data from multiple excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx", parse_cols="A,C,E,G, I, K, M, O, Q, S, U, W, Y, AA, AC, AE, AG, AI, AK, AM, AO, AQ, AS, AU, AW, AY, BA, BC, BE, BG, BI, BK, BM, BO, BQ, BS, BU, BW, BY, CA, CC, CE, CG, CI, CK, CM, CO, CQ, CS, CU, CW, CY, DA, DC, DE, DG, DI, DK, DM, DO, DQ, DS, DU, DW, DY, EA, EC, DE, EG, EI, EK, EM, EO, EQ, ES, EU, EW, EY")
data = data.to_string()
```

How can I change this code to read multiple excel files?
file1.xlsx
file2.xlsx
file5.xlsx

Comment: use iteration? output or desired results would be nice.

Comment: Will you need to parse the same columns?

Comment: pd.read_excel I want to use once for multiple files. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, parse same Columns for all different excel files

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your argument to `parse_cols` is correct. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks for function below.

Comment: Parse columns works ok, using it long time

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function to read your `.xlsx` files and then call it in a list comprehension.

```
import pandas as pd

def parse(file):
    data = pd.read_excel(file, parse_cols="...")
    return data.to_string()

data = [parse(f) for f in ['file1.xlsx', 'file2.xlsx', 'file5.xlsx']]
```

Comment: hi @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, do you have any ideas how this could be done?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751996/selecting-and-importing-only-certain-columns-from-excel-for-importing

Comment: @Nguyen Sorry, I did not see this earlier, but I stand by my comment on your other question.